# Multiple validators for single complex type data property

Tags: angularjs, validation, breeze, complextype

I have come across a scenario where two data properties using the same complex type. Below is the entity used.

```
    {
        "name": "dataProperty1",
        "complexTypeName": "ComplexType:#test"
    },
    {
        "name": "dataProperty2",
        "complexTypeName": "ComplexType:#test"
    }
```

ComplexType:

```
{
    "shortName": "ComplexType",
    "namespace": "test",
    "isComplexType": true,
    "dataProperties": [
            {
            "name": "fieldA",
            "dataType": "String",
            "maxLength": 50
        }
]
}
```

Now my problem is , both data properties (dataProperty1 and dataProperty2) are having a specific validation for the complex type data property (fieldA).

I tried to add two different validators for the complex data property(fieldA), but both validators are  executing for both the data properties.

```
            {
                "name": "fieldA",
                "dataType": "String",
                "maxLength": 50,
                "validators"[
                      {
                         //name :validationA
                      },
                      {
                         //name :validationB
                      }
                 ]
            }
```

**Let's say for 'dataProperty1' only the 'validationA' needs to be executed and for 'dataProperty2' only the 'validationB' needs to be executed.**

Any thing specifically needs to be handled for this scenario?

Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your validation function the 'context' parameter will have a 'propertyName' property.  This 'propertyName' will be the path to your property, so you can distinguish between say 'billingAddress' and 'locationAddress'. Further, if you validate the subproperty of a complexType the 'context.propertyName' will be a dotted path to your property, i.e. something like 'billingAddress.city' vs 'locationAddress.city'.

So you might write a validator like this

```
  var valFn = function (v, context) {
    var propName = context.propertyName;
    // change the validation logic here depending on the 'propName';
  };
  var myValidator = new Validator("MyValidator", valFn,
      { messageTemplate: "Custom message template..." });
```

Comment: I am able to get the property name in the validator, but how do I want to skip the validator already registered with breeze. Let's say only one validator needs to be executed for 'billingAddress.city' but two validators are registered for the 'city' complex type property. Or,is there any way to do a two different validation for a same complex type property used in different data property?

Comment: Have the validator check the propertyName and perform a noop if it isn't relevant. i.e the validator will always execute but it will always succeed for any 'city' property except 'billingAddress.city'.

Comment: I think I am making it more complicate. Let it be simple , a required validator is there in a complex type data property called 'city'. The complex type is used by two data properties 'property1' and 'property2'. Now,I want the city to be required only for 'property1' not for 'property2'. ANy suggestion for this case?

Comment: What I said above. Create a single 'city' validator and inside the validator check if the propertyName is 'property1.city' and if so perform your validation, if the propertyName is 'property2.city' simply return true. ( i.e. validation always succeeds for 'property2.city')

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My another question is , if we have two validators for a single complex property(city) , say for property1.city I have to run one validator and for property2.city I have to run another validator.is this scenario can be handled in a similar way or how it can be handled?

Comment: same thing, use a single validator that forks its logic depending on the complex property path that is being validated.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to show the different error message for 'property1' and 'property2'. i.e I will do a separate logic for both property1.city and property2.city in the city validator.In Breeze schema I can set only one message template for a validator,so how to show two entirely different error messages for the property1 and property2?